# Trouble understanding this set theory answer.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I received feedback from a quiz and was a little confused with the correct answer.

This is the question:

> Which of the following is NOT true of the set S = {{a}, {a, b}, b}?`

a. $\{a\}$ is a member of $S$.

b. $\{b\}$ is a subset of $S$.

c. $\{a, b\}$ is a subset of $S$.

d. $\{\{a, b\}, b\}$ is a subset of $S$.

The **correct** answer is $c.$, but isn't $\{a, b\}$ a subset of $S$? Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If $S = \{x,y,z\}$, then $y$ is not a subset of $S$, but $\{y\}$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\{a,b \}$ to be a subset of $S$, each element would have to be member of $S$. However, $S$ doesn't contain the element $a$. The statement would be true if it said $\{ \{a\}, b \}$ is a subset of $S$. The thing is, $\{a \}$ refers to the *set* that contains only the element $a$, whereas $\{ \{ a\} \}$ refers to the set that contains only the set that contains the element $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$\{a,b\}$ is not a subset of of $S$ because $a \notin S$. Hence $C$ is not true.

Comment: Oh...get it now... Thank you!